# Is the group of elements $t \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $A +t = A$ up to measure $0$ closed?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, group-actions

My question:

> If $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable subset and $t_n \rightarrow t$ is a convergent sequence such that $A +t_n = A$ mod $\mu$, does $A+t=A$ mod $\mu$ hold?

Here $A = B$ mod $\mu$ means that $\mu(A \Delta B)=0$ where $A \Delta B$ is the symmetric difference between $A$ and $B$ and $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A'$ be an intersection of $A+kt_n$ for all $k\in\mathbb Z,n\in\mathbb N$. Since all those sets are equal up to sets of measure zero, $A=A'\mod\mu$ and moreover $A'=A'+t_n$ for each $n$. Unless $t_n$ is eventually constant (in which case the statement is trivial), this implies that $A'$ is invariant under translations by a subgroup of $\mathbb R$ which is dense. Standard ergodicity results imply that a set $A'$ invariant under such set of translations either has measure zero or its complement has measure zero. It follows that $A'=A'+t\mod\mu$ for any $t\in\mathbb R$, in particular for $t=\lim_{n\to\infty}t_n$.

Comment: The "ergodicity result" that I have in mind, is the following: let $\Gamma \subset G$ be a dense subgroup of a compact topological group, then $\Gamma$ acts ergodically on $G$. Can you give a reference how it extends to the noncompact case, or at least when $G = \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I don't know a good reference, but here is an outline. Let $A$ be a $\Gamma$-invariant Lebesgue-measurable set. Directly from the definition of Lebesgue measure we can deduce there is an interval $I$ in which $A$ has density at least $1-\varepsilon$. By $\Gamma$-invariance, $A$ has density at least $1-2\varepsilon$ in any interval of the same length as $I$. We conclude $A$ has full measure.